# Production of interleave video frames

Tags: c#, c++, image, video, interleave

I am developing a simple TV Character Generator software. I need to capture a window and write that pixels on a video card buffer in real-time.
(the window has some animation and video and text.)

It is working great now for progressive formats, But my problem is the interlaced output.( PAL 720x576i format)

I think that I should do the following steps to make each interleave frame:

1 - capture the window in time1 as image
2 - Extract field1 (Even field)
3 - capture the window in time2 as image
4 - Extract field2 (Odd field)
5 - Integration the Field1 and the Field2 to get frame1

(If I am wrong please correct me.)

So, I need to make the fields from images to get interleave frames.

**Note**: I know that some tools can do it, but I want implementation it for myself.

Please give me idea , algorithm , source code (.net or c++) or etc to make an interleave frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best article about interleave video and video fields.

[All About Video Fields](http://lurkertech.com/lg/fields/).

Thanks to Chris Pirazzi.