# The fastest way to copy the odd/even rows (only odd or only even) of a bitmap pixels to another

Tags: c#, c++, loops, video, pixel

I want to make interleave video frames. (Please see [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571672/production-of-interleave-video-frames))

So I need to copy odd rows (only) of the pixels of a bitmap to another.

I do this with the following code:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
    public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint count);
    .....
    //Width=720,Height=576
        data1 = bitmap1.LockBits(rect1 , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
            , System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        data2 = bitmap2.LockBits(rect2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly
            , System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

  unsafe{
            byte* srcPointer = null; byte* dstPointer =null;
            int i = 1;
            while (i < bitmap2.Height)
            {
                srcPointer = (byte*)data2.Scan0 + i * data2.Stride;
                dstPointer = (byte*)data1.Scan0 + i * data1.Stride;
                CopyMemory((IntPtr)dstPointer, (IntPtr)srcPointer, (uint)(data2.Stride));
                i += 2;
            }
        } 
        bitmap1.UnlockBits(data1);
        bitmap2.UnlockBits(data2);
```

It takes about 10 milliseconds. (on Win7 64bit Core i7 Ram=4GB).
Using `for-loop` instead of the `CopyMemory` it takes about 23 ms.
Using `memcpy` instead of the `CopyMemory` takes about 13 ms.
Using `MoveMemory` instead of the `CopyMemory` takes about 15 ms.

**UPDATE:**
when I copy whole the pixels (not only odd rows ) by one CopyMemory command (without the while-loop) it takes about 3ms. like this:

```
  unsafe{
       CopyMemory((IntPtr)((byte*)data1.Scan0), (IntPtr)((byte*)data2.Scan0), (uint)(data2.Stride*bitmap2.Height));
        } 
        bitmap1.UnlockBits(data1);
        bitmap2.UnlockBits(data2);
```

3ms is great for me ,But I want to copy odd rows only (not whole the pixels).

**1- Is there a faster way to do it?**

**2 - What percentage will go faster if I do it by MFC instead of C# ?** (Approximately)

Comment: Since it is in C#, why did you tag with C++ as well?

Comment: Where's your declaration of CopyMemory?

Comment: @Ben , it is:   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
        public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint count);

Comment: Compiling with full release mode optimisation? (Optimize code checked)?

Comment: @Ben , yes.  checked Optimize code in build tab and it is in release mode.

Comment: Then it's unlikely you will get noticeable improvement from moving to C++. 5% at most I would say, likely nearer 1%. Most of the effort is already by CopyMemory, which is highly tuned assembler. You might try RtlCopyMemory from NTDll.dll but I don't think you will see any difference at all, since I think it's just a loader redirect.

Comment: @Ben ,Thanks for your reply. but when I copy whole the pixels (not only odd rows ) by one CopyMemory command (without the while-loop) it takes less than 4 milliseconds.

Comment: Save the height and stride in local variables instead of accessing the field every loop

Comment: @Ben , Thanks, about 300 microseconds improved.

Comment: Eliminate the casts by changing src and dest to IntPtr, and eliminate the multiplication and the access to the field Scan0 by doing pointer += Stride instead.

Comment: @Ben , Thank you again, about 400 microseconds improved. But it is still not ideal for me.

Comment: OK, have you tried the for-loop but using `int32*` instead of `byte*`?

Comment: @Ben , Wow ,using `int32*` and `for-loop` time=~11ms  , that is not ideal for me but is less than half of `byte*` time.

Comment: If stride is divisible by 8 and scan0 is divisible by 8 you might try int64*

Comment: @Ben ,Unfortunately, I realized that cause of reducing time using int32 is due to remove `height` and `stride` from the loop, So not much different between using `byte*` ,`int32*` or `int64*`.(sorry for my English) - using `byte*` ~11.5ms,using `int32*` ~11ms,using `int64*` also ~11ms